# Covering numbers and distributions

Tags: probability, geometry, concentration-of-measure

If given a convex, compact set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with finite volume having a minimum cardinality $\epsilon$-net denoted by $\mathcal{N}_\epsilon$, is it possible to find a continuous probability distribution over $A$ such that sampling $O(|\mathcal{N}_\epsilon|)$ points from the distribution would give an $\epsilon$-net or an "almost" $\epsilon$-net (in some sense) with high probability?

Any work pointing in a similar direction would be helpful.

Comment: If you don't require a continuous distribution and sample without replacement, then $1_{\mathcal N_\epsilon}/|\mathcal N_\epsilon|$ works a treat! Okay - while I assume you want a continuous distribution to avoid nonsensically trivial solutions like that, you might want to reflect on why I needed "sample without replacement" in that and what it means for your real problem.

Comment: Haha, yes I need a continuous distribution (edited the question accordingly). However, the more important point is that $\mathcal{N}_\epsilon$ is unknown, so if one has a distribution over $A$, one could sample and get an approximate net. Hence, a continuous distribution with peaks at points in $\mathcal{N}_\epsilon$ would not be useful.

Comment: Also, instead of sampling without replacement, one could put a condition that the next point is only picked from outside a $2\epsilon$ ball around the previous point. Such a scheme would terminate to give some $\epsilon$-net, I just want it to take $O(|\mathcal{N}_\epsilon|)$ steps.